# node: command not found with two /npm/npm in path

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting the following error when I run npm start or node server.js in my in terminal

node: command not found

I checked other threads. Many have asked to add the path to the env file, which I tried but still, the error is the same.

The suggested path is - /c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/

but the path in my error  is:

/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/npm: line 12: node: command not found

why do I have two 'npm'(/npm/npm) folders in my path? When I check the AppData folder it is empty. Are these folders are hidden? Can anyone please help me to rectify it.

Comment: Command not found means you have not installed npm correctly. Reinstall it.

Comment: hmmm... but I have been using node and react for the past 6 months.   This problem showed up after I tried to add Mongo shell path to env file. Hope I didn't delete something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added 4 paths to env folder then it started working 
C:\Program Files\nodejs 
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin 
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
C:\Windows\System32\

Not sure all these paths were required or not but its working now.